# Programatically choosing a variable number of gridview rows to format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview where I format a specific number of cells for specific rows:

```
protected void hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1 || e.Row.RowIndex == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EAFDB3");
                e.Row.Cells[i].Font.Bold = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, the rows that get changed are static (row 1 and 2).

I've added functionality to the gridview and now need a dynamic number of rows formatted (between 2 and 10). The rows will always be next to eachother.

How can choose the rows dynamically?

Comment: There would have to be something you could use to figure out which rows need to be modified, some condition to evaluate.  What types of rows will need to be formatted differently?

Comment: The rows will always have one of the columns = 3

Comment: you can use:  if (e.Row.RowIndex >=2 && e.Row.RowIndex <=10)

Comment: your question isn't intelligible